# sql server configuration manager says it is on a 32 bit machine and it is not. Should we change that?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016, powershell, configuration-manager

when running the following script for [Determining 32/64 bit in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977657/determining-32-64-bit-in-powershell)

```
cls
if ((gwmi win32_operatingsystem | select osarchitecture).osarchitecture -eq "64-bit")
{
    #64 bit logic here
    Write "64-bit OS"
}
else
{
    #32 bit logic here
    Write "32-bit OS"
}
```

I get a nice reply back:

> 64-bit OS

However, when running the [sql server configuration manager](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157487/sql-server-2016-configuration-manager-wmi-problem)

I get it is running on 32 bits as you can see on the picture below.

[image]

now 2 questions:

where is sql server looking at to say it is running on a 32 bits system?

how do I change that?

*ok 3rd question*, is it worth changing?

Comment: I suspect it's a bug as I've confirmed the same behavior on one of my x64 systems.  One way to get the OS bit level via a TSQL command is to use [xp_msver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-msver-transact-sql).  I also stick with `SELECT @@VERSION` to get the bit-level of the SQL Binaries just in case that's of interest.  I don't think it's worth your time looking into why this flag is wrong, as there are other ways to find the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is misleading and according to some post it is a bug. You cannot change it.

Here is the connect item.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/332566/in-configuration-manager-running-under-64-bit-os-proprty-is-set-as-no-where-it-is-installed-on-x64

See the response from Microsoft's Sam Lester.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e83b5ded-8cda-468d-ac36-1b8c31b1073b/running-under-64bit-os?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade

> It turns out that the label is very confusing.  There is a bug filed
>   on it in the SQL bug database and it will hopefully get fixed in the
>   future to make this clearer.  It turns out that this field shows if
>   you are running a 32-bit version of SQL under a 64-bit OS (as in WoW).
>   I had an X64 machine here with a 64-bit instance of SQL and a 32-bit
>   instance of SQL.  The field shows "No" for the 64-bit version of SQL
>   and "Yes" for the 32-bit version of SQL.  A bit misleading, but
>   "correct" if you look at it in this way.  :)

Comment: glad to hear that then